# Share data with WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm wondering if I can send text data from my Android application to WhatsApp without showing the contacts list of WhatsApp, I just need to set the message and the mobile number internally in my Android code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public void sendWhatsappMessageToMsisdn(String contactNumber)
{
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + contactNumber);
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
       intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the message you want to send");
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
}
```

Comment: this method explores to the contact chat, but I want to make an intent and feed it with the contact number and the message body, when I start the activity it sends the message to that number implicitly without showing WhatsApp

Comment: You don't want to show WhatsApp? If so, afaik  it's not possible (and rightly so, this can lead to undesired behaviour by applications).

Comment: Can I send number and message body, then when I do "startActivity" it opens the WhatsApp and the message I made in java is already sent ?

Comment: No. Eventually the user needs to do the sending.

Comment: okay, let's forget the sending, I need to send number and body, then I move to WhatsApp to press the send button

Comment: It transfers me to the right conversation, but the message body hasn't been transferred from java ! field is empty !